# Class 'OAuth' not found in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\l.twitter-test.com\index.php

Tags: php, oauth

## Environment

- Windows 8 Enterprise (x64)
- PHP 5.3.28 x86
- Error Logging: `E_ALL | E_STRICT`
- Display Errors: `On`
- `php_oauth` 5.3.27 downloaded with image `php_oauth-1.2.3-5.3-ts-vc9-x86`

## What I've Tried

- Answers here on SO (but they lead to tasks I've already completed)
- Verbose error logging (in hopes I'd get something more than the error stated)
- Restart IIS
- Make sure the `php_oauth.dll` is *unblocked*

This is the line that's failing:

```
$oauth = new OAuth("{key}", "{key}");
```

Can somebody shed some light on why this extension won't work?

### php.ini

```
extension=php_oauth.dll
```

Comment: @zerkms, what specifically do you want out of `phpInfo()`?

Comment: check if the extension is loaded

Comment: @zerkms: I see - okay so it doesn't seem to be. But how can I find out why? It's listed in the `php.ini`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this----

```
define('YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
define('YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
```

and use it give name of class and create class object and use it..........